# Xcode 7 build failed due to ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I have been struggling to get my xcode project to build for the last couple hours. I keep getting the following error:

> ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried almost everything. I saw that the Google Developers website said to use pod 'Google/Analytics', even after trying almost everything I could find on StackOverflow and Google regarding the error, I have had absolutely no luck.

I upgraded to XCode 7 yesterday, everything seemed to work yesterday but today suddenly I started getting this error.

If someone has anything I can do about this error, please help!

Pointing me in the right direction to get it fixed would be awesome too!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you please post the whole error message ?

Comment: put it in the question, not in the comment

Comment: @Mr.T - I have updated my question

Comment: what does your podfile contain?

Comment: Does your podfile have pod 'GoogleAnalytics'  ?

Comment: Yes. Following is what I have in my podfile

> pod 'MWPhotoBrowser'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'AppsFlyer-SDK'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

Comment: do you have google services- info plist?

Comment: try adding pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0' in your pof file and remove the existing pod 'googleanalytics' and then do pod install

Comment: I do not have google services-info.plist. I will try to add pod 'Google/Analytics', '~>1.0.0' and get back to you. I have already tried pod 'Google/Analytics' but that resulted in the same error.

Comment: you need to have google services info .plist

Comment: go here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?hl=en and get a configuration file

Comment: just drag and drop that config file to your project

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help. Is it okay if I message you back if there are any further issues?

Comment: Sure....whenever you can!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90407/discussion-between-aashay-and-mr-t).

Comment: @Mr.T - Hi, I have finally solved the issue! Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 8):

The linker flag has been renamed to:

```
-lGoogleAnalytics
```

but the Cocoapods settings have not been updated yet. Rename the entry in "Other Linker Flags" and your problem will be solved.

Also, the library (as of the moment I write is version 3.13.0) does not support Bitcode yet, thus please turn off Bitcode in Build Options > Enable Bitcode > Select "No". Clean & Rebuild afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I commented on the other answer, I reset the Other Linker Flags and it started working.
I was just wondering, would Apple reject my app with a disabled bitcode?

Comment: thank you. If I understand correctly, the Bitcode needs to be enabled if I am releasing a watchOS app as well, right?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem occurred in my project. What I did, I just updated all my pods and after that my app got compiled.

Run "pod update" command from terminal in your project directory where the pod file is located.

Answer (score 3):

1. Please make sure you opened .xcworkspace not .xcodeproj.
2. Go to Library Search Paths in Build settings and 
   add

   1. $(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos
   2. $(inherited)
3. pod install again.

   Update cocoapods to the newest version that supports 64 arch.

   **sudo gem update cocoapods**

   Delete all Valid Architectures and Re-Add the architectures that you just removed.

   **Clean and run**

Answer (score 1):

Without looking directly at your build settings, there's a number of things that could be causing this. The main issue is in your linker flags you likely have something lingering/incorrect. Most of your pods have the prefix of:

```
-lPods-WhichIt-SomePodsLib
```

However your GoogleAnalyticsLibrary has the prefix:

```
-lGoogleAnalyticsServices
```

This might indicate a lingering flag from your. Try looking for this entry in Other Linker Flags (Under Build Settings) and clear this out and re-running pod install.

Other things to check:

- Cocoapods version is latest stable version
- You are using the latest version of Google's official [Analytics pod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=googleanalytics)
- Your library/framework search paths (build settings) are correctly pointing to the analytics library in question.

For the record, I've had issues with pods and using google libs before they officially started releasing in cocoapods. If all else fails, remove the pod entry from your Podfile and try adding the library manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I reset the Other Linker Flags, Library Search Paths, etc and tried to re-install all my pods, and I finally got it working yesterday.
As you said, I suspected something to do with the linker flags but couldn't figure out how to fix it.
Thanks again!